# Not compatible with RN 0.60 autolinking

Tags: react-native

error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-sqlite-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-sqlite-storage")
  - react-native-webview (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-webview")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.

Answer (score 2):

That error explains what's happening: you have linked some packages using `react-native link`.

In react-native 0.60 this is not needed as the linking is done by react-native itself.

To get rid of them you have to use react-native unlink on all your linked packages, that are listed in the error.

Mind that you will probably have to update some of them as autolinking isn't supported in some libraries.

So, to remove it painlessly, i would suggest to do as follows:

1) `react-native unlink packageName` .  //unlink one package

2) run the app to see if it broke. If it broke `npm update packageName`.
If you are developing on iOS it's good to also do `cd ios && pod install`, so you link it trough cocoapods (that's added by default in react-native projects > 0.60)

3) If it keeps breaking, link it and notify the library maintainers.

4) Repeat.

This is the safest way of doing this, so I would suggest to follow those steps

Comment: damn I didn't unlink each one, I just updated the packages and `pod update` & `pod install`ed them, then `react-native link`ed each...still going through my upgrade I hope this works 

Comment: That's works if all the libraries you are using are updated to support autolinking, if not you'll get an error on one of the packages and you have to find which one failed. If you don't have an error that explains exactly where the problems comes it'll be painful and you'll have to test each package and see which one have that error. (and that's just for one error). Hope you'll get trough the update process!